# MPMoviePlayerController : Play progressive video at 10 seconds preload and caching for offline use

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsurlcache, progressive

I can use URLCACHE to fully download a progressive movie, which i can then play.

However, i'd like to start playing the movie after it partially downloads and continue to have it fully download into the cache folder for offline use.

Any ideas / examples?